# Logstash: replacement of the Coralogix/Ruby output plugin with http output plugin requires x2 resources

Tags: http, logging, plugins, output, logstash

According to the Coralogix they are going to drop support of
their Coralogix/Ruby based plugin.

As the replacement it is proposed to use http output plugin.
You can find the relevant details by navigating the URL below:
https://coralogix.com/docs/coralogix-logstash-integration/

The behaviour of the system before integration:
The messages are supplied to the Kafka topic with 50 partitions (input).
As the output was used the Coralogix/Ruby plugin and in was able to handle
the workload with the 10 instances
of the same pipeline which used
the Coralogix/Ruby based plugin.

The behavior of the system after the integration:
1.The successful case:
Logstash pipeline can handle the workload of the production from
the Kafka topic with 50 partitions
with 20 pipelines (instead of 10 with Coralogix/Ruby)
which in turn significantly increases
the expences for this part of the infrastructure
(ec2 c2.8xlarge - 992$ per month).

The solutuin works but its price is 2 times
higher than the original one (Coralogix/Ruby)
You can find the sample of the output configuration below.

I would like also to mention that for this setup the value of the
pool_max = 50 by default

```
output {
        http {
            url => "${CORALOGIX_MAIN_API_URL}"
            http_method => "post"
            headers => ["private_key", "${CORALOGIX_MAIN_PRIVKEY}"]
                format => "json_batch"
                codec => "json"
                mapping => {
                    "applicationName" => "${ENVIRONMENT}"
                    "subsystemName" => "${SUBSYSTEM}"
                    "text" => "%%{[@metadata][event]}"
                }
                http_compression => true
                automatic_retries => 5
                retry_non_idempotent => false
                connect_timeout => 60
                keepalive => true
                pool_max => 50
        }
}
```

2. Attempt to optimise the expences
   In attempt to optimise the expences (decrease a number of pipelines from 20)
   I tried to increase the pool_max value to 300 during a set of probes
   and managed to handle the workload with a noticable lags for 4 or 5 hours,
   after this period I got a high Lag of non consumed messages and had to stop the test
   (13 pipelines were not able to handle the workload)

> ```
> output {
>         http {
>             url => "${CORALOGIX_MAIN_API_URL}"
>             http_method => "post"
>             headers => ["private_key", "${CORALOGIX_MAIN_PRIVKEY}"]
>                 format => "json_batch"
>                 codec => "json"
>                 mapping => {
>                     "applicationName" => "${ENVIRONMENT}"
>                     "subsystemName" => "${SUBSYSTEM}"
>                     "text" => "%%{[@metadata][event]}"
>                 }
>                 http_compression => true
>                 automatic_retries => 5
>                 retry_non_idempotent => false
>                 connect_timeout => 60
>                 keepalive => true
>                 pool_max => 300
>         }
> }
> ```

Question:
Is this expected behavior for the http plugin?
I mean the high number of logstash pipeline instances,
supposedly equal or less equal to the number of the Kafka topic partitions?
In my case Kafka topic partitions = 50 and 40 pipelines were able to cover the load
instead of the 20 with Coralogix/Ruby.
Is there any other/additional approach that could decrease a cost of this solution and a number of the logstash pipelines that handle the worload?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is Roy from Coralogix

I would like to explain the main reasons for the decision about moving to the HTTP plugin and stop the support for the Coralogix plugin

1. In Coralogix our approach is to use native integrations that are generic and open source this includes the "output" plugins
2. The logstash http output plugin supports multiple cores and thus it support higher throughput

Regarding your specific issue I would suggest to adjust the pipeline.batch.size and pipeline.batch.delay configuration
if you are using the default than increase the batch to 400 and the delay to 150 and retest and contact our support with updates on the results

Coralogix 24x7 Support is available and our support engineers or experts can set a call with you to discuss in more details the implementation of your solution and help you find the best solution

Answer (score 0):

After some tests it seems that I found the solution for the issue that I mentioned above.

The settings that should optimize the performance of the http output plugin
should be done on Logstash level (logstash.yml) and not on plugin level (the configuration file which affects the behavior of the http output plugin).

The 2 settings below (you can find the hint about them in Roy's answer) helped to keep the same number of pipelines (10) and handle the production load:

```
pipeline.batch.size: 400
pipeline.batch.delay: 150
```

Both parameters by default have the smaller values that were not sifficient to
handle the production load:

```
pipeline.batch.size: 125
pipeline.batch.delay: 50
```

You can read more about these values by navigating the URL:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-settings-file.html